# How to find the Joint coordinates(X,Y,Z) ,also how to draw a locus of the tracked joint?

Tags: kinect, gesture, kinect-sdk

I am trying to develop a logic to recognize a circle which is made by users right hand, I got the code to draw the skeleton and track from the sample code,

```
private void SensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[0];

        using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            if (skeletonFrame != null)
            {
                skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
                skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
            }
        }

        using (DrawingContext dc = this.drawingGroup.Open())
        {
            // Draw a transparent background to set the render size
            dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight));

            if (skeletons.Length != 0)
            {
                foreach (Skeleton skel in skeletons)
                {
                    RenderClippedEdges(skel, dc);

                    if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                    {
                        this.DrawBonesAndJoints(skel, dc);
                    }
                    else if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.PositionOnly)
                    {
                        dc.DrawEllipse(
                        this.centerPointBrush,
                        null,
                        this.SkeletonPointToScreen(skel.Position),
                        BodyCenterThickness,
                        BodyCenterThickness);
                    }
                }
            }

            // prevent drawing outside of our render area
            this.drawingGroup.ClipGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight));
        }
    }
```

What I want to do now is to track the coordinates of users right hand for gesture recognition,

Here is how I am planning to get the job done:

1. Start the gesture
2. Draw the circled gesture, Make sure to store the coordinates for start and then keep noting the coordinates for every 45 degree shift of the Joint from the start, for 8 octants we will get 8 samples.
3. For making a decision that a circle was drawn we can just check the relation ship between the eight samples.

Also, in the depthimage I want to show the locus of the drawn gesture, so as the handpoint moves it leaves a trace behind so at the end we will get a figure which was drawn by an user. I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Have you tried doing the logic you spell out above?

Comment: Hi,I want to get the coordinates of the right hand joint. So far i havnt been able to get the (X,Y,Z) coordinates of the Right hand.Also for second part of my question, i need to display a locus (a path) of the movement of right hand joint,so if we are looking at skeleton view and the user draws a  circle gesture then we would see the path followed by right hand joint on the skeleton view. i hope my question is clear :/ do let me know if it still isnt.

Comment: How were you thinking of detecting the start of the gesture? It would be easier to detect the end, when you have a record of the last _n_ points from which you can interpolate a circle...

Comment: I was thinking of making a start gesture switch, for example the right hand moves towards the kinect twice to (cud be done by Z coordinate, i think) once that has been processed i can start recording the gesture. Any better ideas on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coordinates for each joint are available for each tracked skeleton during each SkeletonFrameReady event.  Inside your `foreach` loop...

```
foreach (Skeleton skeleton in skeletons) {
    // get the joint
    Joint rightHand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight];

    // get the individual points of the right hand
    double rightX = rightHand.Position.X;
    double rightY = rightHand.Position.Y;
    double rightZ = rightHand.Position.Z;
}
```

You can look at the `JointType` enum to pull out any of the joints and work with the individual coordinates.

To draw your gesture trail you can use the `DrawContext` you have in your example or use another way to draw a `Path` onto the visual layer.  With your x/y/z values, you would need to scale them to the window coordinates.  The "Coding4Fun" library offers a pre-built function to do it; alternatively you can write your own, for example:

```
private static double ScaleY(Joint joint)
{
    double y = ((SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight / 0.4) * -joint.Position.Y) + (SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight / 2);
    return y;
}

private static void ScaleXY(Joint shoulderCenter, bool rightHand, Joint joint, out int scaledX, out int scaledY)
{
    double screenWidth = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;

    double x = 0;
    double y = ScaleY(joint);

    // if rightHand then place shouldCenter on left of screen
    // else place shouldCenter on right of screen
    if (rightHand)
    {
        x = (joint.Position.X - shoulderCenter.Position.X) * screenWidth * 2;
    }
    else
    {
        x = screenWidth - ((shoulderCenter.Position.X - joint.Position.X) * (screenWidth * 2));
    }


    if (x < 0)
    {
        x = 0;
    }
    else if (x > screenWidth - 5)
    {
        x = screenWidth - 5;
    }

    if (y < 0)
    {
        y = 0;
    }

    scaledX = (int)x;
    scaledY = (int)y;
}
```